# replace both filename and filename's content relying solely on pattern found on the name-of-the-file

Tags: sed, grep, replace, pattern-matching

I'd like to know if it's possible to replace both `filename.ext` and a matched pattern inside its content regarding a pattern founded on the *filename* itself using `sed` (and `grep` also, maybe?).

Let me show you as an example a few files that you may re-create with:

```
cat > '[2022] Diary 2022 (essay, Travels).txt' <<\EOF
TITLE/- Diary 2022 (essay, Travels) -\TITLE

@

sometext...
EOF
```

```
cat > '[2022] Diary 2022 (list, Recipes).txt' <<\EOF
TITLE/- Diary 2022 (list, Recipes) -\TITLE

@

sometext...
EOF
```

```
cat > '[2022] Diary 2022 (watchlist, Movies-).txt' <<\EOF
TITLE/- Diary 2022 (watchlist, Movies-) -\TITLE

@

sometext...
EOF
```

```
cat > '[2022] Diary 2022 (list, Movies+).txt' <<\EOF
TITLE/- Diary 2022 (list, Movies+) -\TITLE

@

sometext...
EOF
```

The matching pattern I want to work with is (human-reading from right to left) *everything in between the **ending close parenthesis** and the **1st encountered space***.

I'd say this pattern is base on the **position**, rather than *word* or *digits* or *anything else*.

*Foo Bar foobar (foob, **MATCH**).ext*

I think this should be the right regexp > `\(.+\s(\w.+)\)`

I'd like things to became like this:

`[2022] Diary 2022 (essay, Travels).txt` > becomes > `travels.txt`
and its content becomes >

```
TITLE/- travels -\TITLE

@

sometext...
```

`[2022] Diary 2022 (watchlist, Movies-).txt` > becomes > `movies-.txt`
and its content becomes >

```
TITLE/- movies- -\TITLE

@

sometext...
```

`[2022] Diary 2022 (list, Movies+).txt` > becomes > `movies+.txt`
and its content becomes >

```
TITLE/- movies+ -\TITLE

@

sometext...
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can't do that kind of file renaming so you would additionally need something else, such as a shell script using `mv`.

If you have a version of `bash` with `mapfile`, doing both renaming and modification is simple:

**modfile**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o noclobber

for filename; do
    if [[ $filename =~ ^'['[0-9]+']'[[:space:]]+(.*[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)')')'.txt'$ ]]; then

        old='TITLE/- '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' -\TITLE'
        new='TITLE/- '${BASH_REMATCH[2]}' -\TITLE'
        out=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.txt

        mapfile -d '' data <"$filename"
        printf '%s' "${data//"$old"/"$new"}" >"$out"
        # rm "$filename"
    fi
done
```

```
$ chmod +x modfile
$ ./modfile *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
rename_and_edit() {
  {
    printf 'TITLE/- %s -\\TITLE\n' $2:r &&
     tail -n+2
  } < $1 > $2 &&
    rm -f -- $1
}
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -P rename_and_edit '* (*)\)(.txt)' '$1:l$2'
```

That replaces the first line of the file with the new title regardless of what that first line contained. To instead replace all occurrences of the old title with the new wherever they occur:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
rename_and_edit() {
  local oldtitle="TITLE/- $1:r -\\TITLE" \
        newtitle="TITLE/- $2:r -\\TITLE"
  print -rn -- ${mapfile[$1]//$oldtitle/$newtitle} > $2 &&
    rm -f -- $1
}
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -P rename_and_edit '* (*)\)(.txt)' '$1:l$2'
```

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
rename_and_edit() {
  3=( 'TITLE/- '$^@:r' -\TITLE' )
  print -rn -- ${mapfile[$1]//$3/$4} > $2 &&
    rm -f -- $1
}
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -P rename_and_edit '* (*)\)(.txt)' '$1:l$2'
```